DAX Calculation from Minimum Date to Total Sums causing headache
I have a data set where I am trying to calculate an accounts spend during a time period. In order to calculate it I need to use a Min([Date]) which when summing or totalling, then takes the min date of every account. Below is my formula, the PeriodDate[PeriodStartDate] is a calculated column that takes the inital start date and creates a new date on the aniversary every year to track what is being spent annually.
Period Amount =
CALCULATE(
SUM(Amount]),
DATESINPERIOD(dimdate[DATE],Min(PeriodDate[PeriodStartDate]),
TODAY()-Min(PeriodDate[PeriodStartDate]),DAY)
)

This is how my data displays in a PowerBI Table. The line is correctly calculating the period amount from the Period Start to today. But the total is off because when it does it for both it takes the min date of 6/1/2024 for both Accounts which is incorrect for Account 1A.
Account PeriodStartDate Initial Date    Period Amount
1A  9/1/2024    9/1/2022    100
2A  6/1/2024    6/1/2020    200
Total                           500
Below here is the data it is pulling from. The only 1A amount I would want to pull is the 10/1/2024.
Account Date    Amount
1A  7/1/2024    100
1A  8/1/2024    100
1A  10/1/2024   100
2A  7/1/2024    100
2A  8/1/2024    100
Total               500
Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!!
Account PeriodStartDate Initial Date    Period Amount
1A  9/1/2024    9/1/2022    100
2A  6/1/2024    6/1/2020    200
Total                           300

could you pls provide the sample data in the markdown table https://tabletomarkdown.com/  and the expected output as well
